# Need advice on handling complex state updates with React/Redux or server?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Consider this scenario: Liking a post

When a user likes a post, I want to instantly show the post liked without waiting for a response from the server, instantly update the post's like count, and also display the total count of the user's likes on their profile. That's updating the `post` entity, `postLike` entity, and the `user` entity all in one action.

I care about showing the post liked and the likes count instantly, but don't care about the user's total like count on their profile right at that moment.

**The problem**

In some cases, the post likes should be shown for a specific user on their profile, while other cases not. There are other limitations and edge cases like this.

I also cannot split the above action in to separate actions to, for example, load the user's likes on their profile when it is mounted.

I have 2 options here:

1. Put the logic of updating each piece of state in Redux
2. Offload what isn't critical to the server, and use that response to update the state

Option 1 means having many reducers that have to have the logic in place to deal with the instant updates. So this means putting and maintaining business logic in the frontend.

Option 2 means leaving only what is critical to Redux, and offloading much of the rest to the server, and have the server return the appropriate response with the correct data.

**Example**

In the above scenario, it's either manually add the `postLike`, update the `postLikes` count, and update the user profile in Redux. Otherwise, it's updating only the `postLike` and the post count, and waiting for the server to respond with the updated user that has the updated count, and have one general reducer take care of updating the entire user.

It basically comes down to having this logic in the frontend or backend. Neither is right nor wrong, but I would like to hear some advice from others on the matter.

What would be a good strategy to take here?

Comment: It sounds like you may be interested in optimistic state updates, where you update the state on the front end with the expected results of the HTTP request, and patch/revert once the actual response comes back. There are plenty of articles/libraries online that can help you out.

Comment: I already have those!